# Calculate time difference between text entering in UITextField in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I have one UITextField. I want to calculate the time difference between two input characters. For example if I enter "a" and waits for 3 seconds to enter second character. How to calculate that time.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, use the UItextField delegate method, it calls after every char get enter into field

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return YES; //we allow the user to enter anything
}
```

inside you can setup your method which can check previous input time

Comment: what are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of Date as

```
NSDate *m_date = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval m_secondsBetweenTwoEdits;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{  
    //reset the m_date in this method
    m_date = [NSDate date];        
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
}
```

Use the delegate method of UITextField

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // calculate the difference between two edits
    m_secondsBetweenTwoEdits = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:m_date];
    // reset the m_date variable
    m_date = [NSDate date];
    return YES; //we allow the user to enter anything
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic/method to find Time difference in seconds.

```
NSDate *characterInputTime ;
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   NSInteger differenceInSec = 0;

   if(characterInputTime){
     NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate: characterInputTime
                                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     options:0];

    differenceInSec = [components second];
   }

 // Do whatever you want to do with Time difference.
   characterInputTime = [NSDate date];

   return YES; //we allow the user to enter anything
}
```

Also you can use NSMinuteCalendarUnit if you want to check difference in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

First you should set your class as your textField's delegate by

```
self.myTextfield.delegate = self;
```

Now you should implement the following function from `UITextFieldDelegate`. Also, declare an `NSDate` object named lastDate in your header file. It wouldn't print for the first one, but it would print difference for the later ones.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (lastDate)
    {
        NSLog(@"time diff %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate]);
    }
    lastDate = [NSDate date];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger count;


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if(self.timer){
         // Reset timer if already running
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer=nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"Character entered after %ld seconds",(long)self.count);
    // Reset count & initialize timer again
    self.count=0;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(incrementCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (void)incrementCount{
    self.count++;
}
```

Make sure you set your textfield's delegate to `self`